# Spring Boot - Read custom properties file using Constants class

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I am having a constants class wherein all the Constants have been defined. The values for the constants lies in my custom properties file and the property file resides in a package. I am trying to read the value in the custom property file using my Constants class.

my Constant class

```
package com.example.demo.properties

public interface AppConstant {
//my custom constants
String REQUEST_SUCCESS = "REQUEST_SUCCESS";
String INTERNAL_ERROR = "INTERNAL_ERROR";
String REQUEST_FAIL = "REQUEST_FAIL";
}
```

AppProps.properties

```
//values for constants in properties file
//package com.example.demo.properties
REQUEST_SUCCESS = Request was successful
INTERNAL_ERROR = Internal Error
REQUEST_FAIL = Request Failed due to error
```

I am trying to read the properties file using java.util.Properties. Can someone show me how the value can be read using Spring Boot annotations.

Comment: `Spring boot` also have `@value` annotation,

Comment: @emotionlessbananas ```@Value``` should be used in the Constants class?

Comment: IMHO constant interfaces are very old school. Why you need it.

Answer (score 1):

Add `AppProps.properties` file to the `resources` folder and then add below annotation to above your class that want to use properties

```
@PropertySource("classpath:AppProps.properties")
```

and then use `Value` annotation like below:

```
@Value("${REQUEST_SUCCESS}")
private String requestSuccess;
```