# How to read a variable from a yaml file into the application.properties?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, yaml, application.properties

In my project I have my `application.properties`. Also the are some variables-yamls in the root of the project. Is it possible make the application.properties file read a variable from the yaml file?

I need a property `service.name` to have the same value as the `name` in the vars-dev.yaml.

A `service.name=${name}` did not work

Comment: Is it a spring-boot project?

Comment: @SukhpalSingh yes, this is a spring boot project

Comment: See this question and its answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60911288/spring-boot-read-custom-properties-file-using-constants-class/60911604#60911604

Comment: @Nasir Please read my question properly. I dont want to assign a value to a field of a class. I want to assign a value to a variable in `.properties` from a yaml file

Answer (score 0):

Spring will first load your .yml file and then your .properties file. If you want to use any value from your .yml file then first thing you need to do is use different key in your .properties file for service.name

Project Structure:

[image]

.yml file content:

[image]

Use of value from yml file in java:

[image]

```
.yml file

name :  TestServiceName
```

```
.properties file

service.name=${name}
```

This will load the value specified in .yml file

Comment: When using `service.name=${name}` Suddenly I am getting an Error. `Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not resolve placeholder 'name' in value "${name}"`

Comment: the names are not the same. In .propeties it is `service.name`, in yaml it is `name`

Comment: Maybe the Problem is that the yaml files is NOT in the resource folder like the .properties file? Yaml is in the root of the project (and i cant move it, it is specified by the customer)

Comment: Location of yml file should not be a issue, even if the yml file is in root folder and .properties in resource folder it should use value from .yml file.

Comment: But i am getting exceptions.

Comment: You might be getting IllegalArgumentException because your application is not able to get .yml file and hence it is giving this exception. Can you check if you can directly access value from yml file.

Comment: You mean something like @Value on a yaml file? I tried. Java does not recognises the property

Comment: Please see i have updated my answer with my project structure and use of value in java from yml file.